# Find the closure of the set in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Find the closure of the set in $\mathbb R^2$:

> $S=${$(x,y): x\in(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q},y=\sin(1/x)$} w.r.t usual topology on $\mathbb R^2$
>   .

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

- First, the restriction of $x$ to the rational numbers: how would you handle this? I mean: forgetting for a moment about the rest of the problem, what would the closure of $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology be?
- Secondly, the $\sin (1/x)$. Have you ever drawn the graph of this function? If not, do it.   :-)  [Hint: You surely know the graph of the $\sin x$ function, don't you? Then, try to imagine what happens when you invert all its graph from $x=1$ to $x=+\infty$ and put it inside $(0,1]$, which is exactly what that $1/x$ does.] Once you have convinced yourself about how the graph of $\sin (1/x)$ looks like, think about the points on the $y$-axis between $y=-1$ and $y =+1$. They are *pretty close* to this graph, aren't they?

Comment: For the first point the closure should be [0,1].

Comment: For the 2nd one , I have seen the graph....and the problem is of rapidly increasing oscillation near 0....

Comment: And this rapidly increasing oscillation approaches any points as close as you want...?

Comment: Is the closure of the set is {(x,sin(1/x): x in (0,1]}union {y axis intersection [-1,1]}?

Comment: Yep, it is.    :-)